# Spring Security requires entrypoint and missing bean type

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security on a Spring MVC application. Unlike other examples I am implementing the interface UserDetailsService. I have created a bean for that which I will post below. I am right now directly redirected to Access Denied page. I believe it is because of entry-point-ref. But unfortunately my HomePage is my Loginpage, there is a dropdown HTML5 menu which handles it.

LoginService

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired private UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            UserDetails userDetails = null;
            User user = userDao.findByName(username);
            if(user == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");} //Never specify which one was it exactly
        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(user);
    }
}
```

Security application context xml

```
       <import resource="servlet-context.xml" />

<!-- Global Security settings -->
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />


<!-- Spring Security framework settings -->
<security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="formAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="5" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"/>
    </security:session-management>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" requires-channel="any" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="any" access="permitAll" />
    <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="siteminderFilter" />
</security:http>
<!-- queries to be run on data -->
<beans:bean id="formAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"
        />

<bean id="siteminderFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="principalRequestHeader" value="ROLE_USER"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
        <bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"  class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
            <property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImplementation"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="LoginServiceImplementation" class="com.WirTauschen.service.LoginServiceImpl"></bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: You use both Java and XML for configuring Spring Security, I recommend not to mix. Pick your poison.

Comment: I also suspected the same, I would like to avoid the Java file named WebSecurityConfigurer above, as I am already implementing userDetailsService and userDetails. Can I delete the java file without compromising anything? Also, whats the deal with the entrypoint?

Comment: You can probably rewrite your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to XML. An entry point is like login page.

Comment: Unfortunately my Login page is my homepage, where there  is a HTMl dropdown menu which logs in. I have removed the WebSecurityConfigurer. And added some of the stuff in XML. Please have a look at security-applicationContext.xml, I am editing post now.

Comment: Apparently you want to use preauthentication but haven't setup a pre authentication filter. So nothing is going to be filled.

Comment: I have added the filter. But I get denied page all the time, no errors in catalina.out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your security-applicationContext.xml file

```
<http pattern="/login" security="none"/>
```

Comment: I would like to mention that my homepage which is /users is my login page. I have a HTML5 dropdown menu which has a form for login..